# How to install drivers for NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200 on Precise

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

Ok, I'm a total Linux noob. I was able to install 12.4 without issue, except that it says in the system settings that the graphics card/driver is "unknown".

I have NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200, and have not been able to get it installed. I've found the driver at NVIDIA but couldn't figure out how to actually install it. I found instructions that used apt-get to automatically find the current driver and install it, and that came close. At least then it showed up in the 3rd party drivers list. It said it was installed but not being used? And I was unable to find out why that might be, or how to get the system to use it

Two questions:
1. CAN/SHOULD my graphics card work with 12.4?
2. If so, HOW?

I'm running a 100% fresh install, so what's the step-by-step from there?

Comment: Have your NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200 worked with the Ubuntu 12.04 and enabled watching TV? I need to use it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question: NO YOU CAN'T INSTALL LEGACY NVIDIA DRIVER (173.14.XX) ON 
A 32bit INSTALL. They're just not compatible with the new Xorg system. There are rumors of an update in the future, and if I understand correctly there may already be a 64bit one released. But for now, the only solution (not a solution, more like a compromise) is to downgrade Xorg.

**EDIT:**
They've now released an updated driver for 32bit systems, 173.14.35. You can grab it from the launchpad site (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173-updates/173.14.35-0ubuntu1/+build/3597638). It installed easily, and so far I haven't run into any glitches!

**EDIT:**
For what it's worth, this fix covers a LOT of legacy nvidia products. Here's a list of devices that use (require) 173.14.xx drivers (from [www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-173.14.31-driver.html](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-173.14.31-driver.html)):

> GeForce 200 series:
>   GTX 280, GTX 260
>
> GeForce 9 series:
>   9800 GX2, 9800 GTX/GTX+, 9800 GT, 9600 GT, 9600 GSO, 9500 GT
>
> GeForce 8 series:
>   8800 Ultra, 8800 GTX, 8800 GTS 512, 8800 GTS, 8800 GT, 8800 GS, 8600 GTS, 8600 GT, 8600  GS, 8500 GT, 8400 SE, 8400 GS, 8400, 8300 GS, 8300, 8200 / nForce 730a, 8200, 8100 / nForce 720a
>
> GeForce 7 series:
>   7950 GX2, 7950 GT, 7900 GTX, 7900 GT/GTO, 7900 GS, 7800 SLI, 7800 GTX, 7800 GS, 7650 GS, 7600 LE, 7600 GT, 7600 GS, 7550 LE, 7500 LE, 7350 LE, 7300 SE / 7200 GS, 7300 LE,  7300 GT, 7300 GS, 7150 / NVIDIA nForce 630i, 7100 GS, 7100 / NVIDIA nForce 630i, 7100 / NVIDIA nForce 620i, 7050 PV / NVIDIA nForce 630a, 7050 / NVIDIA nForce 630i, 7050 / NVIDIA nForce 610i, 7025 / NVIDIA nForce 630a
>
> GeForce 6 series:
>   6800 XT, 6800 XE, 6800 Ultra, 6800 LE, 6800 GT, 6800 GS/XT, 6800 GS, 6800, 6700 XL, 6610 XL, 6600 VE, 6600 LE, 6600 GT, 6600, 6500, 6250, 6200 TurboCache, 6200SE TurboCache, 6200 LE, 6200 A-LE, 6200, 6150SE nForce 430, 6150LE / Quadro NVS 210S, 6150 LE, 6150, 6100 nForce 420, 6100 nForce 405, 6100 nForce 400, 6100
>
> GeForce 5 FX series:
>   PCX 5900, PCX 5750, PCX 5300, FX 5950 Ultra, FX 5900ZT, FX 5900XT, FX 5900 Ultra, FX 5900, FX 5800 Ultra, FX 5800, FX 5700VE, FX 5700 Ultra, FX 5700LE, FX 5700, FX 5600XT, FX 5600 Ultra, FX 5600, FX 5500, FX 5200 Ultra, FX 5200LE, FX 5200, FX 5100
>
> Quadro FX series:
>   FX 700, FX 570, FX 5600, FX 560, FX 5500, FX 550, FX 540, FX 500/FX 600, FX 4700 X2, FX 4600, FX 4500 X2, FX 4500, FX 4000, FX 3700, FX 370, FX 3500, FX 350, FX 3450, FX 3400/4400, FX 330, FX 3000, FX 2000, FX 1700, FX 1500, FX 1400, FX 1300, FX 1100, FX 1000
>
> Quadro FX Notebook series:
>   FX 570M, FX 370M, FX 360M, FX 3600M, FX 2700M, FX 1700M, FX 1600M
>
> Quadro NVS series:
>   NVS 440, NVS 290, NVS 285
>
> Quadro Plex series:
>   Model IV, Model II
>
> Quadro G-Sync series:
>   G-Sync II, G-Sync I
>
> Quadro SDI series:
>   Quadro SDI
>
> GPU Computing Processor series:
>   Tesla C870

www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-173.14.31-driver.html

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience, using 12.04 without the drivers causes it to freeze frequently when running more than one task at a time.

If you've already run the apt-get method for the current driver by installing 'nvidia-current', you should be fine.  You can confirm by typing in `nvidia-settings` into Terminal and launching that or by launching Additional Drivers from the Dash Home menu.

If you haven't already installed 'nvidia-current', the instructions are as follows:

Go into Terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and finally,

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

You'll have to restart after this.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, just to confirm: I went back to square one and reinstalled 12.4. So, my next step will start with "sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates", correct? I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Almost there. Ran all the apt-get lines and rebooted. Now system details say "VESA: NV34 Board - p162-11n" for Graphics. But the additional drivers section says my Nvidia driver is activated but not in use. Running nvidia-settings successfully opens the settings window, but I get a warning: "You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server."  What changes should I make to the config file...and how?

Comment: Ok, I opened terminal, typed 'sudoku nvidia-xconfig' and restarted. Now, my desktop looks like  its zoomed in -- everything is HUGE! And nvidia x server settings still says I'm not using the driver? Help!

Comment: Looked in kern.log... Turns out that this method installs the wrong driver. It installs 302.17, but apparently I need 173.14.xx

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an Nvidia Quadro 600 and since I was frustrated that I couldn't get a 120hz 1080p resolution option with the GUI installed nvidia-current drivers, I decided to use the above mentioned APT method (listed on a different site) to install the 302.17 drivers for the Quadro 600, which of course broke X due to being an unsupported driver and on my system Nouveau was removed (by the nvidia install?).
So I had nothing to fall back on.

I suggest that if you are using a Nvidia driver, you only use the driver specified by the additional hardware in the GUI and avoid using the APT method unless you have compared the driver versions from the PPA and have verified that you are indeed installing the correct driver.

As a noob, I was unable to remove the incorrect modules with the command line which resulted in a fresh install with no Nvidia card attached, then shutdown, install the Nvidia card and use the GUI to add the `nvidia-current` drivers to get 1080p and everything works. (I'm sure there was a better/easier/faster way but this was all I could figure out by myself).

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia's updated 173.14.35 driver for the FX5200 is now available through the `jockey` application or "Additional Drivers".

In Xubuntu 12.04 I use: Menu > Settings > Additional Drivers. This opens a GUI listing the drivers available for the video card. Select the recommended proprietary driver. You'll have to reboot the system after changing the video driver to activate it; I always just shut it down and do a cold-boot.