# How to get Ubuntu 12.10 nVidia FX 5200 Driver to work?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, graphics

Right now I have an older Dell Dimension 3000, of which inside is a Pentium 4, 1GB RAM and an nVidia FX 5200. I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237922/how-to-use-my-nvidia-fx-5200-in-ubuntu) which asked the same thing, but the only answer as a comment was of no use. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153915/how-to-install-drivers-for-nvidia-geforce-fx-5200-on-precise) was more detailed and provided a more sufficient answer, but upon visiting the [launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173-updates/173.14.35-0ubuntu1/+build/3597638) and grabbing the built .deb files for Quantal as listed. I downloaded this in browser, and opened it using the Ubuntu Software Centre application. It would not allow me to install this because *"Dependency is not satisfiable: xorg-video-abi-11"*

Unsure what to do, I attempted to install the nVidia officially released driver for an x86 system and I was told that I was running and xorg server and that I could not install the driver. I have tried several other methods with similar responses, or leaving the system unbootable. Is there a way to bypass this xorg issue, or would I have to downgrade?

Note: *This set up is temporary while my regular computer is waiting for a replacement part, I only need this to get work done without having a delay in even moving the mouse.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop X on Ubuntu to install the official nVidia drivers, hit `Ctrl+Alt+F1` login, then type `sudo service lightdm stop`

You should then be able to run the installer from the command line without the X error message.  When your done with the install (there will be a few errors, ignore them), restart and all should be good.

This is how i was able to install the 6200 drivers on 12.04LTS at least.

Comment: Oh okay, let me try that.

Comment: Nvidia required I disable noveau and reboot, yet when disabled the computer needs to reboot and without it I cannot access grub or tty.

Comment: I have no idea why disabling noveau would break grub, but to fix common boot errors, i use boot repair from an ubuntu live disk - see option 2 here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair