# Ubuntu running extemely slow

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on my Toshiba Satellite P20 and it runs extremely slow and jerky with freezing at times. It is running along side windows 7 ultimate and it may have something to do with the graphics card. When upgrading from xp to windows 7 I found out my Nvidia graphics card is not compatible with windows7 and it defaults to the standard vga graphics adapter. Ubuntu sees the graphics adapter as a Vesa: NV34 Board-e133-1nz. After the install of ubuntu i could only boot up in recovey mode because the screen would freeze but was fixed by adding nomodeset but it still runs extremely slow and jerky. If you need more info let me know (I am new at this but very interested and want to learn, thank you for your help).

Comment: Related. http://askubuntu.com/questions/153915/how-to-install-drivers-for-nvidia-geforce-fx-5200-on-precise

Comment: "It is running along side windows 7...". That means Ubuntu and Windows are running at the same time, which, in turn, means you must have installed Ubuntu in a virtual machine. Is that the case? If not, how did you get the two running?

Comment: If I'm not using this forum correctly tell me. When doing install of Ubuntu I had the install along side window option, so now when I boot my computer I have the choice of running Ubuntu or Windows, maybe my terminology is wrong. They don't actually run at the same time. I have allocated 16GB of memory for Ubuntu.

Comment: Problem fixed by installing xubuntu desktop, works for me this topic can be closed.