# Ubuntu 13.04 with Nvidia Geforce FX 5200

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 13.04

I installed pure Ubuntu 13.04 and tried to install the restricted driver,but it became yellow-screen after reboot.
I found this question: [Ubuntu 13.04 - installation Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291199/help-13-04-installation-nvidia-driver)

I do in this way:

```
apt-get remove nvidia*
apt-get install build-essential linux-source linux-headers-`uname -r`
apt-get install  nvidia-current
depmod -a
depmod -a
modprobe nvidia_current
```

but it says:

```
FATAL: Module nvidia_current not found.
```

so I typed

```
modprobe nvidia_304
lsmod
```

which shows, that `nvidia` is loaded, but when I ran

```
/etc/init.d/lightdm restart
```

and logged in, I can only see the background!
Then I ran

nvidia-xconfig
reboot

and when it's rebooted, the resolution became small (small? perhaps bad English), and I can still see the background only.
What can I do?

Edit:

```
$ sudo nvidia-settings
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
```

Comment: can you use `nvidia-settings` to configure your graphics?

Comment: @phoeagon No,I can't.  
``$sudo nvidia-settings  

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help`
       for usage information.``

Comment: @gjz010 **Attention**: There is *no underline or something else* before `\`uname -r\``. Use exactly like this: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-\`uname -r\``. And, before, only `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-source linux-headers`

Comment: @Radu sorry,that's only a typing mistake.I did as you say in fact.

Comment: @gjz010 And use those 2 commands separatly, atention the second is conditioned by the results of the first

Comment: I have the same problem with FX5200 With the driver "Nouveau" unity was very slow ... i have found this bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173/+bug/1173890

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153915/how-to-install-drivers-for-nvidia-geforce-fx-5200-on-precise

Answer (score 1):

You should be using nvidia-173, FX5200 is not supported for nvidia-current