# What am I supposed to do to get the most out of my Nvidia GeForce FX 5500 graphics card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lubuntu, 17.10

I am running a fresh installed 32-bit lubuntu on an old desktop machine with Nvidia GeForce FX 5500 graphics card. I have no idea if the graphics card driver is correct or not, how can I get the most out of my graphics card?

```
user@user-System-Name:~$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NV34 [GeForce FX 5500]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm agp agp-3.0 vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=64 maxlatency=1 mingnt=5
       resources: irq:16 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

I have tried to solve my issue with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/155572/634142) but I am neither understanding if it fits my situation nor do I have the knowledge to install the [proposed package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173-updates/173.14.35-0ubuntu1/+build/3597638).

Comment: Nvidia legacy driver 173 is not available in 17.10. The only currently supported Ubuntu release that has it is 14.04. It is supported till April 2019, and if you wish to try it, go with [Xubuntu 14.04.1](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso). Other then that, you probably can't do much more with 14 years old hardware.

Comment: Why then XUbuntu and not [Ubuntu 14.04.5](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) or [LUbuntu 14.04.5](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.5/release/lubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-i386.iso) which the OP is using?

Comment: @derHugo Because Ubuntu has Unity which needs better hardware. You'd get a wallpaper with no panels and window borders, or something similar.  Also, 14.04.5 has updated xorg and kernel from 16.04, and we don't want that.

Comment: @mikewhatever Does that necessarily mean that my current driver is not driving the graphics card effectively?

Comment: Not sure.  Perhaps nouveau does a good job with FX5500. I don't have the hardware to test, on the other hand, you do. Test it if you want to, and also, perhaps explain what you mean by "get the most" . What do you want it to do? Exactly what "issue" do you have with it?

Comment: @mikewhatever How would I test it? Well, I tried using ubuntu 16.04 on that hardware for example and it felt laggy.  I just want to make sure it works up to it's normal clocked potential.

Comment: ...and what is "its normal clicked potential"? Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity has too many visual effects, it's a distro for contemporary hardware. Xubuntu  or Lubuntu 16.04 should probably feel snappier, and Ubuntu server with xmonad even better.

Comment: @mikewhatever I just want to ensure that it _lets_ me run highest end software it can. Without overclocking.

Comment: Well then, you should be happy that it runs 16.04 + Unity - very high end software for something so old. Try different distros, and you'll know what it can and can't do soon enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [mikehatever](https://askubuntu.com/users/20054/mikewhatever)'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/988997/634142#comment1593766_988997):

Nvidia legacy driver 173 is not available in 17.10. The only currently supported Ubuntu release that has it is 14.04. It is supported until April 2019, and if you wish to try it, go with [Xubuntu 14.04.1](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso). Other than that, you probably can't do much more with 14 years old hardware.